# Memory issues with imageswitcher

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-file

I'm trying to load some images onto my ImageSwitcher from a folder in SDCard. I'm creating a runnable and execute in a loop so that the images are displayed one after the other.

```
 final ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
             imageSwitcher.postDelayed(
                     new Runnable() {

                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             i++;

                             File dir = new File("/sdcard/Wallpapers/My Wallpapers");
                             final File file[]=dir.listFiles();

                                 imageSwitcher.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file[i]));
                                 imageSwitcher.postDelayed(this, 2000); 


                         }
                     },
                     2000);
```

Some images work fine, and after a while the app crashes due to "outofmemory" exception.

I tried solving the memory issue by putting this code just below the:

> "imageSwitcher.postDelayed(this, 2000);"

This was the code i put there:

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)imageSwitcher.getNextView(); 
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable(); 
Bitmap b = bd.getBitmap();
b.recycle();
```

This force closes the app with a Nullpointer exception.

I want to know how to handle this memory issue..or where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, with a tradeoff with image quality. I reduced the size of the image and loaded it into a "imageView" and I did not use any imageswitcher.

Comment: as of now, reducing the image size is the only issue to avoid outofmemory error. Hope android will add some API to resize images on the fly or add some way to garbage collect the images from imageswitcher except the currently shown image